# Angular2: Views stored in database

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

I'm working on a GUI prototype using Angular2. One of the most important requirements is to store the HTML code (component's template) in database. Only one solution comes to my mind:

- Create a set of components:

  - my-layout
  - my-field
  - my-text-box
- Save in database something like this:

`<my-layout [rows]="" [cols]=""...>
  <my-field [name]="" [length]=""...></my-field>
  <my-text-box [name]=""...></my-text-box>
 </my-layout>`

- Create a "loader-component" that gets the template from database and loads all the components.

At the moment, i'm trying to create the "loader-component" with no success.It creates a component dynamically but i can't set the data from database as component's template. If i use the "Renderer", it only prints text. It doesn't recognize component's selectors.

Any ideas?

I'm not sure if this approach follows the "Angular-way" and i think we are trying to do something that Angular is not created for.

Someone knows any modern JS library/framework to achieve this???.

Thank you very much!

Comment: *I'm not sure if this approach follows the Angular-way*: I'm sure it doesn't. The whole idea is to create a JS bundle containing the whole component: code, template and style. And the idea is even to go further with AOT: compile the application at build time to build a bundle containing the already compiled component (i.e. replace the template with JS instructions), and avoid bundling the angular templae compiler with the application. The template is an integral part of the component. It should be unit-tested and versioned with the component code. Storing it in the database looks awful to me.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your comment!. I agree with you, looks awful and, as you said, you can't test it.